# How to use mwapi library to get a wikipedia page?

Tags: python, session, get

I have been trying to figure out the documentation of the `mwapi` library (MediaWiki API) and I cannot figure out how to simply request a page based on a search query or keyword. I know I should use `get()` but filling in the parameters with keywords yield errors. Does anyone know how this works to look up something like "Earth Wind and Fire"?

Documentation can be found here: 
http://pythonhosted.org/mwapi

and here is the only example they have of get() being used

```
import mwapi

session = mwapi.Session('https://en.wikipedia.org')

print(session.get(action='query', meta='userinfo'))
```

`{'query': {'userinfo': {'anon': '', 'name': '75.72.203.28', 'id': 0}}, 'batchcomplete': ''}`

```
print(session.get(action='query', prop='revisions', revids=32423425))
```

`{'query': {'pages': {'1429626': {'ns': 0, 'revisions': [{'user': 'Wknight94', 'parentid': 32276615, 'comment': '/* References */ Removing less-specific cat', 'revid': 32423425, 'timestamp': '2005-12-23T00:07:17Z'}], 'title': 'Grigol Ordzhonikidze', 'pageid': 1429626}}}, 'batchcomplete': ''}`

Comment: Which parameters are you filling in with keywords? Show the api and usage that is failing.

Comment: session = mwapi.Session(host = "https://en.wikipedia.org", user_agent= "myinfo")

Comment: session.get(action='query', params = {"Earth Wind and Fire"})

Comment: output: 

The following query raised warnings: {'action': 'query', 'params': 'Earth Wind and Fire', 'format': 'json'}
 - main -- {'*': 'Unrecognized parameter: params.'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you understand the API:

```
import json  # Used only to pretty-print dictionaries.
import mwapi

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.6) Gecko/2009011913  Firefox'

session = mwapi.Session('https://en.wikipedia.org', user_agent=USER_AGENT)

query = session.get(action='query', titles='Earth Wind and Fire')
print('query returned:')
print(json.dumps(query, indent=4))

pages = query['query']['pages']
if pages:
    print('\npages:')
    for pageid in pages:
        data = session.get(action='parse', pageid=pageid, prop='text')
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
query returned:
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "313370": {
                "pageid": 313370,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Earth Wind and Fire"
            }
        }
    }
}

pages:
{
    "parse": {
        "title": "Earth Wind and Fire",
        "pageid": 313370,
        "text": {
            "*": "<div class=\"redirectMsg\"><p>Redirect to:</p><ul class=\"redirectText\"><li><a href=\"/wiki/Earth,_Wind_%26_Fire\" title=\"Earth, Wind &amp; Fire\">Earth, Wind &amp; Fire</a></li></ul></div><div class=\"mw-parser-output\">\n\n<!-- \nNewPP limit report\nParsed by mw1279\nCached time: 20171121014700\nCache expiry: 1900800\nDynamic content: false\nCPU time usage: 0.000 seconds\nReal time usage: 0.001 seconds\nPreprocessor visited node count: 0/1000000\nPreprocessor generated node count: 0/1500000\nPost\u2010expand include size: 0/2097152 bytes\nTemplate argument size: 0/2097152 bytes\nHighest expansion depth: 0/40\nExpensive parser function count: 0/500\n-->\n<!--\nTransclusion expansion time report (%,ms,calls,template)\n100.00%    0.000      1 -total\n-->\n</div>\n<!-- Saved in parser cache with key enwiki:pcache:idhash:313370-0!canonical and timestamp 20171121014700 and revision id 16182229\n -->\n"
        }
    }
}
```